# Gmaps4Rails json request Template is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

*Controller:*

```
  # GET /customers/1
  # GET /customers/1.json
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])

    @locations = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@customer.shipping_addresses) do |location, marker|
      marker.lat location.latitude
      marker.lng location.longitude
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/customers/location", :locals => { :object => location})
      marker.title location.name.to_s
    end

    # @locations = @customer.shipping_addresses.to_gmaps4rails do |location, marker|
      # marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/customers/location", :locals => { :object => location})      
      # marker.title location.name.to_s      
    # end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customer }
    end
  end
```

Old version gem(1.5.6) code commented
*View:*

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @locations.to_json %>);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Everything works fine. But if you make a request to the json page. What if there will shipping_address coordinates in error:

Template is missing

```
Missing partial /customers/location with {: locale => [: ru],: formats => [: json],: handlers => [: erb,: builder,: coffee]}. Searched in: * "/ team / mss / app / views" * "/ usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.6/app/views" * "/ usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/views" * "/ usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems / kaminari-0.14.1/app/views "
```

Alternatively I can do a background check on the controller format.

```
unless request.format.json? 
      @locations = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@customer.shipping_addresses) do |location, marker|
        marker.lat location.latitude
        marker.lng location.longitude
        marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/customers/location", :locals => { :object => location})
        marker.title location.name.to_s
      end
    end
```

And if he is not doing json @ locations. Tried to upgrade to the latest version heme stood before 1.5.6, 2.1.1 now. As you consider how to act?

Comment: The template doesnt exist?

Comment: Template exists. And it's great if the type of request is filled html. But I also used json request to this controller action. And in this case just a problem arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/customers/location", :formats => [:html], :locals => { :object => location})
```